# Create content type based on filtered results of other content types?

Tags: nodes

I'd like to create a content type where the user can select criteria from an existing content type to form a unique list of content.

For example, let's say I have a content type called `shoes` with the fields `size`, `color`, and `price`.  (It may not be relevant to the example, but let's say that `size` and `color` are stored as lists, and `price` is stored as a decimal.)

I'd like a user to be able to create a new node of content type called `list` (or something to that effect) where they could select values from the three fields within `shoes`, and store the result as a unique `list` node (e.g. "all size 8 red shoes under $50").

What's the best method to achieve this?  Is this a job for Entity Views Attachment?